# Modal does not display onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I am a bit new to react. I have a modal component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function TaskModal(props) {
   
    return (
    
        <Modal show={props.isHidden} onHide={props.onClose}
        parentselector={() => document.querySelector('#root')}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Translations</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <h4>Filter:</h4>
                <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
                <hr />
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={props.onClose}>Save</Button>
                <Button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
      
    )
}

export default TaskModal;
```

Which is being called in its parent component when a button is clicked

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TaskList from './TaskList';
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import TaskModal from './TaskModal';

function TaskTable() {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const showModal = () => {
        console.log("Show modal click is working");
        setIsOpen(true);
    };

    const hideModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    };

    
    return (
        <>
       
      <div className="task-table">
        
      <TaskModal isHidden={isOpen} onClose={hideModal}/>
        
        <table className="table task-table">
           
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                     
                        <button className="btn" onClick={showModal}>
                            <i className="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button>
                    </th>
                {
                 
                    status.map((item, id) => (
                        <th key={id}>{item}</th>
                    ))
                }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    {status.map((item, id) => (
                        <td className='loop-td' key={id}>
                            <TaskList/>
                        </td>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default TaskTable;
```

And then The TaskTable component is a child of the App component like this

```js
import './App.css';
import TaskTable from './components/TaskTable';

function App() {
  return (
    
     <TaskTable/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click the button I get the log which I put there "Show modal click is working" and I can see the modal when I inspect the elements but for some reasons it does not just show on the screen and gives no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to import the css

Include in your src/index.js or App.js file

> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

[Bootstrap Docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)